R issue with reshape, reshape is not ordering columns correctly
I am trying to use reshape function in R to arrange my data timepoints in a table. The variable that I am using to split it is numerical, but when reshape arranges the table it incorrectly puts 2,0.5,4,6,8,0,24...168, instead of  0.0 ,  0.5  , 2.0  , 4.0  , 6.0  , 8.0 , 24.0 , 48.0... 168.0
Any help is greatly appreciated.
This is my data:

>G2
   Animal Sex  Time  Sugar
1    2001   M   2.0   5880
2    2001   M   0.5     95
3    2001   M   4.0  25100
4    2001   M   6.0  68500
5    2001   M   8.0 110000
6    2001   M   0.0     NA
7    2001   M  24.0 336000
8    2001   M  48.0 476000
9    2001   M  72.0 413000
10   2001   M  96.0 368000
11   2001   M 120.0 332000
12   2001   M 144.0 282000
13   2001   M 168.0 271000
14   2002   M   2.0  13200
15   2002   M   0.5    356
16   2002   M   4.0  55700
17   2002   M   6.0 121000
18   2002   M   8.0 216000
19   2002   M   0.0     NA
20   2002   M  24.0 529000
21   2002   M  48.0 554000
22   2002   M  72.0 468000
23   2002   M  96.0 408000
24   2002   M 120.0 354000
25   2002   M 144.0 348000
26   2002   M 168.0 290000
27   2003   M   2.0  20500
28   2003   M   0.5   1190
29   2003   M   4.0  43800
30   2003   M   6.0  90500
31   2003   M   8.0 142000
32   2003   M   0.0     NA
33   2003   M  24.0 401000
34   2003   M  48.0 485000
35   2003   M  72.0 393000
36   2003   M  96.0 386000
37   2003   M 120.0 335000
38   2003   M 144.0 289000
39   2003   M 168.0 247000
40   2501   F   2.0   6630
41   2501   F   0.5    305
42   2501   F   4.0  28900
43   2501   F   6.0  67300
44   2501   F   8.0 138000
45   2501   F   0.0     NA
46   2501   F  24.0 395000
47   2501   F  48.0 474000
48   2501   F  72.0 390000
49   2501   F  96.0 330000
50   2501   F 120.0 318000
51   2501   F 144.0 258000
52   2501   F 168.0 238000
53   2502   F   2.0   2140
54   2502   F   0.5     NA
55   2502   F   4.0  15700
56   2502   F   6.0  69200
57   2502   F   8.0 125000
58   2502   F   0.0     NA
59   2502   F  24.0 478000
60   2502   F  48.0 500000
61   2502   F  72.0 471000
62   2502   F  96.0 407000
63   2502   F 120.0 414000
64   2502   F 144.0 352000
65   2502   F 168.0 462000
66   2503   F   2.0  32400
67   2503   F   0.5   6290
68   2503   F   4.0  78800
69   2503   F   6.0 119000
70   2503   F   8.0 160000
71   2503   F   0.0     NA
72   2503   F  24.0 328000
73   2503   F  48.0 463000
74   2503   F  72.0 429000
75   2503   F  96.0 381000
76   2503   F 120.0 389000
77   2503   F 144.0 339000
78   2503   F 168.0 327000

I am doing this:
    G2r = reshape(G2, direction = "wide",
             idvar = c("Animal","Sex"), 
             times = Time,
             timevar = "Time"
             )

I am getting this:
> head(G2r)
   Animal Sex Sugar.2 Sugar.0.5 Sugar.4 Sugar.6 Sugar.8 Sugar.24 Sugar.48 Sugar.72 Sugar.96 Sugar.120 Sugar.144 Sugar.168
1    2001   M   5880       95  25100  68500 110000  336000  476000  413000  368000   332000   282000   271000
13   2002   M  13200      356  55700 121000 216000  529000  554000  468000  408000   354000   348000   290000
25   2003   M  20500     1190  43800  90500 142000  401000  485000  393000  386000   335000   289000   247000
37   2501   F   6630      305  28900  67300 138000  395000  474000  390000  330000   318000   258000   238000
49   2502   F   2140       NA  15700  69200 125000  478000  500000  471000  407000   414000   352000   462000
60   2503   F  32400     6290  78800 119000 160000  328000  463000  429000  381000   389000   339000   327000

I tried to sort the time and put it as times = sort(unique(G2$Time)), but it doesn't work.
I also tried na.omit(Time) and na.omit(Sugar) in case the NAs were producing the issue. But it did not work either.

Unfortunately we can't see variable types from how you provided data, edit question either with dput(G2) or str(G2) output.


str(G2)
'data.frame': 78 obs. of  4 variables:
$ Animal: int  2001 2001 2001 2001 2001 2001 2001 2001 2001 2001 ...
$ Sex   : chr  "M" "M" "M" "M" ...
$ Time  : num  2 0.5 4 6 8 0 24 48 72 96 ...
$ Sugar: num  5880 95 25100 68500 110000 NA 336000 476000 413000 368000 ...


You are right. Thank you so much for noticing this.

Note that you can use your edit button in future.

If you sort the data going into reshape() it should get the result you need.
G2[order(G2$Animal, G2$Sex, G2$Time), ] is your data frame in the required order.
G2r = reshape(G2[order(G2$Animal, G2$Sex, G2$Time), ], direction = "wide",
         idvar = c("Animal","Sex"), 
         times = Time,
         timevar = "Time"
         )

G2r
#    Animal Sex Sugar.0 Sugar.0.5 Sugar.2 Sugar.4 Sugar.6 Sugar.8 Sugar.24
# 6    2001   M      NA        95    5880   25100   68500  110000   336000
# 19   2002   M      NA       356   13200   55700  121000  216000   529000
# 32   2003   M      NA      1190   20500   43800   90500  142000   401000
# 45   2501   F      NA       305    6630   28900   67300  138000   395000
# 58   2502   F      NA        NA    2140   15700   69200  125000   478000
# 71   2503   F      NA      6290   32400   78800  119000  160000   328000
#    Sugar.48 Sugar.72 Sugar.96 Sugar.120 Sugar.144 Sugar.168
# 6    476000   413000   368000    332000    282000    271000
# 19   554000   468000   408000    354000    348000    290000
# 32   485000   393000   386000    335000    289000    247000
# 45   474000   390000   330000    318000    258000    238000
# 58   500000   471000   407000    414000    352000    462000
# 71   463000   429000   381000    389000    339000    327000



Nice! +1 reshape(G2[do.call('order', G2), ], ...  would be more concise.

Thanks @shaun_m! It makes sense now. Loving this community!
